Converting the parametric equations $(x,y)=( \cos(2t)+\sin(t)-\cos(t)-2t, -\sin(t)+\sin(2t)-\cos(t)+1 )$ to Cartesian form
I have been working on getting a function that describes the surface needed to 'smoothly' roll a square.  There are existing formulas that rely on the catenary function, but they seem to force either the square to rotate non-linearly or the surface to translate non-linearly.  I was hoping to find a function for a surface that would allow both the square to rotate uniformly/linearly (with constant angular momentum) and for the surface to translate linearly.
I think (think being the operative word) that I have found a parametric function that does this to my satisfaction, but I would love to be able to remove the t variable and translate it back into a cartesian formula.  I will include a Desmos link here to the function: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ra1qk5lale . The formula I would like to translate is C, with Q being the places where C and the square are tangent (this may not be relevant).
Any help is appreciated!  Thank you for your time.
$$C(t)=( \cos(2t)+\sin(t)-\cos(t)-2t, -\sin(t)+\sin(2t)-\cos(t)+1 )$$


Did you mean $\cos(2t)$ instead of $\cos(2)$?

@jjagmath I think so because the Desmos has $\cos (2t)$ rather than $\cos (2)$. I edited it accordingly.

WolframAlpha doesn't seem to be much help here.

Oh, sorry about the typo!  Thank you @CyclotomicField.

I just added to your text a picture of the parametric curve for $t \in (0,15)$. One thing is sure : no polynomial expression $f(x,y)=0$ will be obtainable for such a curve.

One can verify that
$$\left(\;\left(x + 2t\right)^2 - \left(1 + 2 y - y^2\right) \;\right)^2 = 1 + 4 y \tag1$$
(See Addendum 2 for how I got there.) We can solve this for $t$ to get
$$ t \;=\; \frac12\left(\;-x\; \pm_1\; \sqrt{1 + 2 y - y^2 \;\pm_2\; \sqrt{1 + 4 y}}\;\right) \tag2$$
where $\pm_1$ and $\pm_2$ are independent choices of sign, giving four solutions. For $t\in[0,\pi/4]$ (which corresponds to half of the above-the-$x$-axis "small" arc in the plotted path), we use respective signs $+$ and $-$:
$$ t \;=\; \frac12\left(\;-x\; +\; \sqrt{1 + 2 y - y^2 \;-\; \sqrt{1 + 4 y}}\;\right) \tag3$$
To get the final Cartesian form of the equation, we substitute into, say, the parametric equation for $y$ ...
$$\begin{align}
y &= 1 - \sin t - \cos t + \sin 2t  \tag4\end{align}$$
Here's the Mathematica output:
ContourPlot[
  y == ( 1 - Sin[t] - Cos[t] + Sin[2t]
        /. { t -> 1/2 (-x + Sqrt[1+2y-y^2-Sqrt[1+4y]])}
      ),
 {x, 0, -Pi/2}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]


It should be noted that, having substituted into the $x$ equation (as was done in a previous version of this answer), leads to extraneous solutions:


Addendum. The parameterization as given, to facilitate OP's rolling square animation, starts the path at the origin and traces right-to-left (from $x=0$ to $x=-\pi/2$) as $t$ increases from $0$ to $\pi/4$.
Re-parameterizing with $x\to x+\pi/2$ and $t\to \pi/4-t$ moves the top of the arch to the $y$-axis (specifically, $(0,2-\sqrt{2}))$) and traces the curve left-to-right as $t$ increases. This resulting parametric equations are
$$\begin{align}
x &=  2t \;+\; 
4 \sin t\,\sin\tfrac18(\pi + 4t)\,\sin\tfrac18(\pi - 4t) \\[4pt]
y &= \phantom{2t\;+\;} 
4 \cos t\,\sin\tfrac18(\pi + 4t)\,\sin\tfrac18(\pi - 4t)
\end{align} \tag5$$
The counterpart of equation $(3)$ effectively undergoes a couple of sign changes:
$$t \;=\; \frac12 \left(\;
x - \sqrt{1 + 2 y - y^2 - \sqrt{1 + 4 y}}
\;\right) \tag6$$
The Mathematica output shows the shifted curve:
ContourPlot[
    y == ( 4 Cos[t] Sin[(Pi-4t)/8] Sin[(Pi+4t)/8] 
          /. { t -> 1/2 (x-Sqrt[1+2y-y^2-Sqrt[1+4y]]) }
         ), 
  {x, 0, Pi/2}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic]



Addendum 2. To get to $(1)$, I expanded the trig terms of the parametric equations and converted them to helpful polynomial forms using the tangent half-angle substitutions
$$\sin t = \frac{2s}{1+s^2} \qquad \cos t = \frac{1-s^2}{1+s^2} \qquad s := \tan\tfrac12t \tag7$$
Clearing denominators, I can write
$$\begin{align}
0 &= (x+2t) (1 + s^2)^2 - 2 s + 6 s^2 - 2 s^3 - 2 s^4 \\[4pt]
0 &= y (1 + s^2)^2 - 2 s - 2 s^2 + 6 s^3 - 2 s^4
\end{align} \tag8$$
If the right-hand sides were linear polynomials in $s$, I could easily eliminate that element. Being non-linear, I let Mathematica's Resultant[] function accomplish the same thing, obtaining a quartic polynomial in $t$ that, when set equal to $0$, is equivalent to $(1)$.
I didn't expect things go so well from here, since quartic polynomials aren't generally known for having nice roots. But Mathematica's Solve[] function readily gave me $(2)$; I guess I shouldn't be so quick to judge. :)
Incidentally, it happens that the radicand in $(3)$ and $(6)$ factors:
$$1 + 2 y - y^2 - \sqrt{1 + 4 y} \;=\; z^2 \left(1-2z-z^2\right) \qquad z := \sqrt{y+\frac14}-\frac12 \tag9$$
I don't know if this is particularly helpful, apart from allowing $z$ to be pulled from under the radical.

HOLY COW!  Thank you so much.  I have no idea how you knew to get from my question to step 1, but it seems to work perfectly.  I will have to study your answer for a while to understand it.

@Sol: See Addendum 2 for how I arrived at equation $(1)$.

I did not know about tangent half-angle substitution.  That is incredibly useful, thank you for teaching me about it and for being so helpful/informative!

Here is a cool little animation (what I wanted the function for): https://www.desmos.com/calculator/f800as5dw0

@Sol: ("Math Wizard Blue". Hee!) ... So, you wanted the Cartesian form in order to define a fillable region. I'm not anything beyond the most casual Desmos user, but I believe you can actually accomplish this using parametrics directly, simply by chaining border curves together. Eg, for the region bounded by $f(t)$ (for $0\leq t\leq a$) and $g(t)$ (for $0\leq t\leq b$), you can plot ${t\leq a: f(t), t\geq a: g(t-a)}$ over the range $0\leq t\leq a+b$. (I probably have the notation wrong and may be missing details. (Like, the border may need to be traced ccw all the way around.)) ... Cheers!

Thank you for the Desmos info.  That does indeed work :)  I needed the Cartesian version for a shader I am writing.  The 'belt' looking thing is going to be translated into an animation.  My coding skillz do not extend to writing my own math engine like in Desmos unfortunately, so I am stuck with (u, v) coords for now in there.  Your help is being used right now to make my program prettier!
